# Reload multiple images using jQuery? How to optimize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an update of multiple images using jQuery:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $(".image").each(function (index) {
            base_url = $(this).attr('src').split('?rand=')[0];
            address = base_url + '?rand=' + Math.random();
            $(this).attr("src", address);
        });
    }, 10000);
};
```

I'm trying to improve it:

```
function update() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $(".cameragrid_").find("img").each(function (index) {
            d = new Date();
            var src = $(this)[0].src;
            var state = $(this).context.readyState;
            if (state == 'complete'); {
                $(this).attr("src", src + d.getTime());
            }
        });
        console.log('click');
    }, 10000);
}

$(window).ready(function () {
    $('.cameragrid_').hide();
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('.cameragrid_').show();
    update();
});
```

I wanted to reduce the time from 10 to 3 seconds, but when I reduce this time, do not update all the images, my algorithm and the rest is not updated.
.

Is there any way to optimize it to run within 3 seconds ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code? Are you trying to change the images every 3 seconds? Because if your images are taking longer than 3 seconds to load, that's never going to work.

Comment: Thats exactly what is happening !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having one timer for many images maybe you could try to have many timers, one for each image or at least a small batch of images.

```
window.onload = function () {

    $(".image").each(function (index) {
        setInterval(function () {
             base_url = $(this).attr('src').split('?rand=')[0];
             address = base_url + '?rand=' + Math.random();
             $(this).attr("src", address);
        }, 3000);
    });

};
```

I've not tested this code but you can get the idea, maybe you'll have to add a $.proxy() somewhere to fix the this context.

testing if the image is displayed should be easier this way: https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery

Comment: How to add $.proxy() ?

Comment: $.proxy(function () { alert(); }, this) will return a function in this context, but I'm not sure it is mandatory for your case, was just a possibility

Comment: Is there a way to verify if the reload of an image is complete ?

I´m trying  in this way:

var state = $(this).context.readyState;
              if (state == 'complete'); {
                  $(this).attr("src", src + d.getTime());
              }

Comment: However the var state just return "undefined"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached check this link there is some good pointers

Comment: you should update you're question to reflect you're current code

Answer (score 1):

Hey have you tried https://tinypng.com/ this compress the image format, this will increase some loading time of image more over you can also work on making the sprite of 10 images into 1 in this way loading only one file and then indexing the sprite.

Never personally tried image-min but this is also worth looking.

Believe sprite could solve your problem in shot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended that way:

```
setInterval(function(){

                $( ".image" ).each(function( index ) {

                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = $(this).attr('src');

                    if(img.complete){

                    base_url = $(this).attr('src').split('?rand=')[0];
                    address = base_url + '?rand=' + Math.random();
                    $(this).attr("src", address);

                    }

                });

            },500);
```